# How to fix these errors that have generated while I was installing vim plugins

Tags: vim

Thse are the errors that popup everytime I open vim. Should manually find these files and paste them in the required directory?

```
Error detected while processing /home/tanmay/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/basic.vim:
line   64:
E484: Can't open file /usr/share/vim/delmenu.vim
line   65:
E484: Can't open file /usr/share/vim/menu.vim
line  134:
E484: Can't open file /usr/share/vim/syntax/syntax.vim
line  146:
E254: Cannot allocate color Grey50
Error detected while processing /home/tanmay/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/extended.vim:
line   31:
E254: Cannot allocate color Grey50
Error detected while processing /home/tanmay/.vim_runtime/sources_forked/peaksea/colors/peaksea.vim:
line   33:
E254: Cannot allocate color Grey50
```

Comment: Your vim folders don't make sense and you don't provide any insight into how you did this custom install or what plugins you've tried to install. It's impossible to say how to get you to where you want to be without more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is wrong with your `'runtimepath'`, and your use of non-default personal config locations (`~/.vim_runtime` vs. the default `~/.vim`) suggests that you somehow messed with it.

The `menu.vim` and `syntax/syntax.vim` files are part of Vim's runtime; if they are not available, major functionality of Vim (like syntax highlighting) probably doesn't work right. The file paths for these files are built-into Vim, and depend on how Vim was compiled and packaged. For example, the Vim 7.4 that is provided by Ubuntu 16.04 has a path of `/usr/share/vim/vim74`.

If you start Vim without your personal customizations (`vim --clean`), these errors should not appear (if they persist, you have a broken Vim installation, and should try reinstalling it). You can note down the correct paths (`:echo $VIMRUNTIME`) from there, and correct your personal customization. In general, I would avoid deviating too much from the default structure. With your `sources_forked` subdirectory, you seem to emulate something like Vim's (built-in since late 7.4 versions) [`:help packages`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/repeat.txt.html#packages) feature.

Answer (score -1):

this appens when

.vimrc

and/or subordinate

source vim.init.code.file

are stopped on error.

On my side, my example :When changing vim version, let's say vim70 to vim80,
path inside my source vim.init.code.file 's 
called by .vim  are missing,  because genuinely referenced as

/path/.../vim70

I turned it out whith  a

s/vim70/vimcurrent/

in each of my .vim and subordinates

and I therefore need a link to

cd /usr/share/vim
ls -lsa 
sudo ln -s vim80 vimcurrent

vim /tmp/t.t

ok